I was unable to successfully compile the Xamarin application
I developed a Xamarin application, paired it with a Mac, and successfully ran it on an iOS simulator.
After creating a certificate and provisioning profile and installing them on my Mac and Windows PC,
I can see the correct profile in Xcode and Visual Studio. However, when building the app use a registered iOS device,
I encounter the following errors:
Error description

Xamarin version - 17.8.0.156
Xcode version - 13.2.1

Errors
Error       Failed to codesign '/Users/AAA/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/XXX.iOS/f08c84ed302c76b104472943189fb497ab4d67d9e475aa4e2261e4bee68bf006/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad5.3-15.7/XXX.iOS.app': /Users/AAA/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/XXX.iOS/f08c84ed302c76b104472943189fb497ab4d67d9e475aa4e2261e4bee68bf006/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad5.3-15.7/XXX.iOS.app: cannot find code object on disk    XXX.iOS
Error       /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
/Users/AAA/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/XXX.iOS/f08c84ed302c76b104472943189fb497ab4d67d9e475aa4e2261e4bee68bf006/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad5.3-15.7/XXX.iOS.app: cannot find code object on disk XXX.iOS
Thanks

You should post the errors as text, not as images

@Cincinnatus I added error as text
